# MDO test suite code from architectures folder

Tags: architecture, openmdao

A small doubt. There is a file called mdao_test_suite.py in the architecture folder of openmdao package. Can this file be used for any mdo test suite problem? I want to use it to test automatic architecture(similar to sellar) concept on mdo test suite problems. Is this the purpose of this file or is it meant for something else?

Comment: which version of openmdao is this? can you provide a link to the github code?

Comment: I couldn't find the same file in the openMDAO folder on Github. Maybe that is some other file.

Answer (score 0):

In openmdao 1.x that test suite code was not carried over. Its not functionality that we decided to maintain.

Comment: So is it possible to write a code which can be used for all the algebraic equations. Sort off a sellar one but more general. I am not sure, where to proceed from.

Comment: You could certainly write a code that would loop over a set of pre-determined problems and run each one. Its more than possible, but this is not a development priority for the OpenMDAO team right now.